# Unable to get date out put

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have some date based outputs in my database .I am trying fetch the data from database by comparing dates. but I am unable to get any output

Here is my table:

[image: database table]

and my Sql Query is:

```
 $from_date='2016-12-01';

$query = "SELECT * FROM keywords_rank WHERE date =".$from_date." ";
```

I tried this directly in Sql section but result was empty . even i tried with DATE(date)
i am not getting where i am wrong . any useful help ?

Comment: what type is the date field in the db?

Comment: its 'date' ....

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN keywords_rank` and post the results in your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `keywords_rank` WHERE `date` = '{$from_date}'";
```

You cannot use date alone as date is already a reserved name within mysql.

Also don't forget about SQL injections: if `$from_date` obtained from untrusted source (such as user input), you should escape special characters. Most proper way for that is using prepared statements ([mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)). In this case you don't need an explicit quotes.

Comment: No problem. Are you using mysql_ by any chance?

Comment: @TrendSnaps, you should rename your `date` column to something else.

Comment: You can refer to this website for words to avoid: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html